# Python plumbum: Passing $ in an cmd argument

Tags: python, plumbum

I am trying to execute the following command in python using plumbum:

```
sort -u -f -t$'\t' -k1,1 file1 > file2
```

However, I am having issues passing the `-t$'\t'` argument. Here is my code:

```
from plumbum.cmd import sort
separator = r"-t$'\t'"
print separator
cmd = (sort["-u", "-f", separator, "-k1,1", "file1"]) > "file2"
print cmd
print cmd()
```

I can see problems right away after `print separator` and `print cmd()` executes:

```
-t$'\t'
/usr/bin/sort -u -f "-t\$'\\t'" -k1,1 file1 > file2
```

1. The argument is wrapped in double quotes.
2. An extra \ before $ and \t is inserted.

How should I pass this argument to plumbum?

Comment: Have you tried this: `separator = "-t$'\t'"` ? and you could explain that it's a way to pass TAB as a field separator. BTW you know that this is very, very easy to do using python only right?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the argument looks like this inside of the command :  "-t\$'\\t'" (with double quotes).

Comment: then that should work, try it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The problem is that particular argument is wrapped in double quotes, and an extra \ is added before the $ and \t.

Comment: see my answer below. I made that work, maybe you could try the same trick using `plumbum` but I cannot check since I'm running windows. My solution works using MSYS `sort` command so at least you have something to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have stumbled into limitations of the command line escaping.

I could make it work using `subprocess` module, passing a real tabulation char litteraly:

```
import subprocess

p=subprocess.Popen(["sort","-u","-f","-t\t","-k1,1","file1",">","file2"],shell=True)
p.wait()
```

Also, full python short solution that does what you want:

```
with open("file1") as fr, open("file2","w") as fw:
    fw.writelines(sorted(set(fr),key=lambda x : x.split("\t")[0]))
```

The full python solution doesn't work exactly the same way `sort` does when dealing with unicity. If 2 lines have the same first field but not the same second field, `sort` keeps one of them, whereas the `set` will keep both.

EDIT: unchecked but you just confirmed that it works: just tweak your plumbum code with:

```
separator = "-t\t"
```

could just work, although out of the 3 ones, I'd recommend the full python solution since it doesn't involve an external process and therefore is more pythonic and portable.

Comment: You actually solved it by changing the argument to: "-t\t".  It is simple as that. Thx!

Comment: actually I thought it would solve it, since I had exactly the same problem with `subprocess.Popen` and solved it like that. Very interesting question!

Comment: Thanks for solving this. As for the full python solution, it's much easier to use plumbum, since I am doing a lot of shell scripting. It would make more sense not to use plumbum if this were it.

Comment: okay, I get it, if you run a lot of different commands, yes, keep using `plumbum`. 3 solutions are always better than one. But you'll see that a lot of unix stuff can be a lot faster by using full python, less prone to bugs due to escaping, spaces, etc...